# Need to Show Final Solution in GUI Window

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion

I have written a Tromino Puzzle program that fills up a user specified sized board with tromino's except for a user-specified 'hole' (empty square).

What I need to do now is display the in a GUI window. Showing the board and the trominos with the solution. I am completely lost at how to get my code to display this in a GUI window. ***How would I do this?***

**Note: I have been given a giant DrawingPanel class to use in my code**

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class trominoZ {

        private int[][] grid;
        private int currentNum;

        // Pre-condition: size must be a perfect power of 2 and 0<=x<size, 0<=y<size
        // Post-condition: creates an empty tromino object with dimensions size x size.
        public void tromino(int size, int x, int y) {

            int actualsize = 1;
            while (actualsize < size) actualsize*=2;

            // Make sure the grid size is a perfect power of 2.
            grid = new int[actualsize][actualsize];
            currentNum = 1;

            // Fill in the grid with all empty squares.
            for (int i=0; i<actualsize; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<actualsize; j++) {
                    grid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            // This represents the original hole in the tromino.
            grid[x][y] = -1;
        }

        // Wrapper call for recursive method.
        public void tile() {
            tileRec(grid.length, 0, 0);
        }

        private void tileRec(int size, int topx, int topy) {

            // No recursive case needed here, just fill in your one tromino...
            if (size == 2) {

                // Fill in the one necessary tromino. The hole is identified by a
                // non-zero number, so don't fill in that one square.   
                for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
                    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
                        if (grid[topx+i][topy+j] == 0)
                            grid[topx+i][topy+j] = currentNum;

                // Advance to the next tromino.
                currentNum++;
            }

            // Recursive case...
            else {

                // Find coordinates of missing hole
                int savex=topx, savey=topy;

                for (int x=topx; x<topx+size; x++) 
                    for (int y=topy; y<topy+size; y++)
                        if (grid[x][y] != 0) {
                            savex = x;
                            savey = y;
                        }

                // Hole in upper left quadrant.     
                if (savex < topx + size/2 && savey < topy + size/2) {

                    // Recursively tile upper left quadrant.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);

                    // Fill in middle tromino
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;

                    // Advance to the next tromino
                    currentNum++;

                    // Now we can make our three other recursive calls.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

                }

                // Hole in upper right quadrant
                else if (savex < topx + size/2 && savey >= topy + size/2) {

                    // Recursively tile upper right quadrant.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);

                    // Fill in middle tromino
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                    // Advance to the next tromino
                    currentNum++;

                    // Now we can make our three other recursive calls.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

                }

                // Hole in bottom left quadrant
                else if (savex >= topx + size/2 && savey < topy + size/2) {

                    // Recursively tile bottom left quadrant.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);

                    // Fill in middle tromino
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                    // Advance to the next tromino
                    currentNum++;

                    // Now we can make our three other recursive calls.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);
                }
                else {

                    // Recursively tile bottom right quadrant.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

                    // Fill in middle tromino
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                    grid[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                    // Advance to the next tromino
                    currentNum++;

                    // Now we can make our three other recursive calls.
                    tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                    tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
                }

            } // end large if-else

        } // end tileRec


        // Prints out the current object.
        public void print() {

            for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
                    System.out.print(grid[i][j] + "\t");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Get user input...
            System.out.println("How big do you want your Tromino grid?");
            System.out.println("Please enter a perfect power of 2.");
            int size = stdin.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Where do you want the hole?");
            System.out.println("Answer with an x and y coordinate separated by spaces.");
            int x = stdin.nextInt();
            int y = stdin.nextInt();

            // Create our object and tile it!
            tromino thisguy = new tromino(size, x, y);
            thisguy.tile();

            // Print out the trominoed grid.
            System.out.println("Here's your final grid:\n");
            thisguy.print();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to have happen in this GUI window. I see alot of `System.out.println`s. Did you want these outputs in a GUI or something?

Comment: @peeskillet Precisely. I'm working on a GUI window, I'll update code soon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your `print()` actually print, have it return a String

```
public String print() {
    String printString = "";

    for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++)
            printString += grid[i][j] + "\t");
        }
         printString += "\n";
         // I moved the nextline. I figured this may what you want instead
    }
}
```

Then show message in dialog

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

      tromino thisguy = new tromino(size, x, y);

      // this will print the result in a popup box
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thisguy.print(), "This is your final grid");
      // You need a String as the first argument that's why I changed the 
      // return type of print() to String instead of void
      // and don't print but instead create a string
 }
```

Also, consider Java naming convention.  Class names start with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Although displaying your program via the dialog is a straightforward process, displaying it using Java's built-in Swing framework is much more impressive (and not much harder).

I am unfamiliar with the Tromino puzzle, but if you have a grid of elements that you wish to display, it is a fairly simple task to do so with the Java Swing framework.  You could create a class that extends [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and add it to a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).  Some tutorials that might help:

- https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-gui-tutorial/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/
- http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the resources, will look into them. However I am trying to convert my code so it will display the grid with the tromino's displayed around the missing square in a GUI window using the DrawPanel class. It is looking like I will have to basically re-do my code which is why I am desperately looking for help from someone (if there is an easier way to do it).